# Responsive web interface for Pico W

Tags: web-server, pi-pico

I'm working on a project where I need to control a device remotely using a web page (on a phone) as a remote control - think of it as steering controls for a remote control car. This device also has an IMU, and I want to visualise its compass heading. I've been exploring some web tutorials (they all seem the same), and I have successfully been able to stream data - however, the problem is that each time the Pico W refreshes the data, the webpage needs to reload, so if I'm doing that 10 times a second, that's a lot of refreshes, and it interrupts the user interface.

Is there a way to have a react-style app, whereby a value on a page is reloaded, rather than the whole page? I can't have an actual react app because that requires cloud hosting (as far as I'm aware). I'm exploring the idea of using a custom android app to control the pico, but that's a steep learning curve in itself. The solution needs to exist in an ecosystem consisting of the pico W and an android phone only - no other external web services or resources.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
As a response to the question: "why would you have to refresh the webpage? ... you only have to update the elements that changed".

If you view the video linked below, you'll notice the refresh button and favicon flashing from time to time. This is the page reloading.
https://youtu.be/grxjmrPT1zQ

The code from this example is very similar to most of the other tutorials that I've seen - they take an index.html template document, replace some values and re-serve the whole document.

Here's the code from this example:

```
# Listen for connections
while True:
    try:
        cl, addr = s.accept()
        print('Client connected from', addr)
        cl_file = cl.makefile('rwb', 0)
        while True:
            line = cl_file.readline()
            if not line or line == b'\r\n':
                break
        
        response = get_html('index.html')
        data = accelerometer.acceleration
        tapped = accelerometer.events['tap']
        response = response.replace('AccX', str(data[0]))
        response = response.replace('AccY', str(data[1]))
        response = response.replace('AccZ', str(data[2]))
        if tapped:
            dice_val = str(random.randint(1,6))
        response = response.replace('DiceVal', dice_val)
        
        cl.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
        cl.send(response)
        cl.close()
    except OSError as e:
        cl.close()
        print('Connection closed')
```

Comment: I'll add some detail to the original question.

Comment: your response to my question amounts to `because I saw it on YouTube` ... that is not a good reason to update the whole webpage ... please have a look at this ... the Raspberry Pi can do the same thing ... https://youtu.be/PeK2gAdqjas

Comment: yeah - not quite. my response is an example. The message I'm trying to convey is that I haven't found a better solution, despite searching. 
Thanks for the link - that seems to be more or less what I was expecting.